# Use moment and moment timezone to properly implement diff

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Trying to use moment's diff function to calculate ms difference in time b/w one moment that will always have a constant timezone and another timezone indifferent moment. I'm using moment-timezone to help with this.

Here's my example code:

```
const parisTime   = moment({hour:18, minutes:0}).tz('Europe/Paris');
const currentTime = moment(); //right now
const difference  = moment.duration(parisTime.diff(currentTime))
```

When I perform this operation diff treats currentTime as the same timezone as Europe/Paris which won't work b/c currentTime could be from anywhere in the world.

Any ideas how to resolve this ?
Your help is much  appreciated - correct answer will be marked as so.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to compute the difference between today at 18:00 Paris time and now. That would be

```
moment.tz('18:00', 'HH:mm', 'Europe/Paris').diff(moment());
```

Basically, you need to parse 18:00 as Paris time. What is happening right now is that you are parsing it as local time, and then converting that to Paris time.

Note that because you aren't specifying a date, the day is assumed to be 'today', meaning that this code can result in both positive and negative values.

See [this blog post](https://maggiepint.com/2016/05/14/moment-js-shows-the-wrong-date/) for more information about how moment's constructor functions work.