# How to get time difference moment js?

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs, moment-timezone

I want time difference between client and server. I used diff but getting this error

```
 "TypeError: date.diff is not a function"
```

```js
const date = moment(new Date()).format()
const server = moment.tz("America/Danmarkshavn")
console.log(date.diff(server))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Remove format() call from the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your created dates are invalid it should be something like this :

```
const date1 = moment() //Gives you current date and time
var date2 = moment("2021/04/17") //Creates a date from the given string
date1.diff(date2,"days") //returns the difference between these 2 dates in days
```

Comment: the time zone should be something like this : 
`var dateWithTimezone = moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z");
dateWithTimezone.tz('America/Danmarkshavn')`

Answer (score 0):

`.format` returns a string and not a date

Then you have the additional issue that Damnmarkshavn is not in the timezone package unless you add the JSON to your project

So you may need to add it according to

https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/

However I see it in the [JSON](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/data/packed/latest.json)
`"America/Danmarkshavn|LMT -03 -02 GMT|1e.E 30 20 0|01212121212121212121212121212121213|-2a5WJ.k 2z5fJ.k 19U0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1fA0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1fA0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 DC0|8"`

If you want to know the difference, you need this code adapted from [Use moment and moment timezone to properly implement diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409678/use-moment-and-moment-timezone-to-properly-implement-diff)

Otherwise you get a diff of just 0, 1 or -1 millisecond

So it is 7:55am here now and 05:55 in Greenland, e.g.-2 hours GMT - that is -3 hours here, which is what I get from this code

```js
const date = moment()
console.log(date)
moment.tz.add("America/Danmarkshavn|LMT -03 -02 GMT|1e.E 30 20 0|01212121212121212121212121212121213|-2a5WJ.k 2z5fJ.k 19U0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1fA0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1fA0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 DC0|8");

const diff = moment.tz("07:55", "HH:mm","America/Danmarkshavn").diff(date); // replace 07:55 with your server time
console.log(moment(diff).format("HH.mm"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
```